# Calling a Perl module from Python

Tags: python, perl, module, call

my question is the inverse of [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441766/calling-a-python-module-from-perl). In particular, I've dozens of existing modules written in Perl, some are object oriented and others just export a group of functions. Now since I have to write certain scripts in python but still would like to call those Perl modules, I'm wondering

1) if it is achievable, and

2) if so, what would be the best way of doing it

Ideally, the Perl modules would appear as "black boxes" to Python, so to speak. Something like:

```
 from perl_module import *
 return_value = perl_func(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

and

```
 object = perl_module.new()
 object.method1(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

but I'm sure to achieve this one needs to have something else imported / running at the background, if possible at all. Anything that is the counterpart to the `Inline::Python` would also be nice (but not ideal). Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPerl
2. http://www.boriel.com/files/perlfunc.py

Comment: fyi, pyperl hasn't been under development for a number of years, as far as I can tell from this link

Comment: Reminds me of RSPerl, which has been out of maintenance and is broken at numerous places even though it boasts as the most viable connection from Perl to R... Guess I'll try PyPerl to find out.

Comment: Here is the the original post for perlfunc.py, it explains how to use the module: http://www.boriel.com/2007/01/21/calling-perl-from-python/?lang=en