# How to import and call Python functions from Perl?

Tags: python, perl

I have almost no Perl experience but I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. I have a python module with a bunch of functions and I need to create a Perl wrapper that can call these Python functions.

Edited

```
use Inline Python => <<'END_OF_PYTHON_CODE';
import example_API
END_OF_PYTHON_CODE

   print getPortConfig("google.com", "<port>0</port>");
```

With this I keep getting,
Can't locate Inline.pm in @INC

Edit

How can I install this onto a Windows machine?

Comment: Dod you install Inline::Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Python module from Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441766/calling-a-python-module-from-perl)

Comment: How can I install this on a windows machine?

Comment: Next time, post new questions as new questions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl has a module called Inline::Python in cpan

If it is acceptable, try it. I never use it.